# ReportViewer 9.0 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I am making an application to make Reports using visual studio 2010. Due to old ajax already used in the website, we can not use ReportViewer 10.0. So I am using Report Viewer 9.0 to generate reports.

When I run the Application I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
>   The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

I have changed the 10.0 ReportViewer references with the 9.0 one's. My web.config is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
     <system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
          <!--<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />-->
          <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
         <!--<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->
       <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And my Page's code is as follows:

```xml
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%--<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>--%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rs" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
            InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="dtAuditTableAdapters.ADT_AuditTableAdapter">
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Need solution for below error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
>   The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your datasource

```
<rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
```

with

```
<rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="dtAuditTableAdapters" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Looking at the code you have posted you still seem to be  using `Version=10.0.0.0,` in

```
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
         ........Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, ...
        </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

change  `Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>`

 
to

```
Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

and then it should work

HTH